# How can I move columns in small screen on bootstrap?

Tags: bootstrap-4, responsive, bootstrap-grid

I have 3 columns

---

### (1)  .col-md-4     |  (2)  .col-md-4    |   (3) .col-md-2  |  (4)  .col-md-2

I want this in small screen (Phone / small screen) as:

---

### (1)                           |    (4)   |

### (2)                           |    (3)   |

Comment: Can you show us your current code, ideally as a JSFiddle?

Comment: Try with offset. When the sum of the columns are higher than 12, it automatically goes in a new line

Answer (score 4):

First of all, as far as I can tell you have not 3 but FOUR columns.

Secondly, what you want to do is called reordering. 
You want to reorder the columns below the md breakpoint.

Here's how you do it:

```html
<div class="container">
   <div class="row">
       <div class="col-md-4 order-1 order-md-1">1</div>
       <div class="col-md-4 order-3 order-md-2">2</div>
       <div class="col-md-2 order-4 order-md-3">3</div>
       <div class="col-md-2 order-2 order-md-4">4</div>
   </div>
</div>
```

With `order-md-*` you specify the order for each column from the medium breakpoint onwards.

And with `order-*` you specify the order you want below the medium breakpoint (i.e. that's the default "mobile-first" breakpoint).